# Laravel get intended url

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I use a common httpRequest to login, so I could use `Redirect::intended();` to lead the user to a url before them being lead to the login page.  That all works well.

Now I've changed login to ajax request I can only redirect the url in javascript now. So I've to pass the intended url to front end then do the `window.location=url`

The problem is I can't get the `intended/origina`l url. Can any kind laravel expert help me out ?

Answer (score 23):

In your controller action use:

`$url = Redirect::intended( ... )->getTargetUrl();`

(Where `...` is the fallback url)

Then return it in the JSON response, and use `window.location` or other to do the redirect.

Comment: Worked for me on Laravel 5.1. Be sure to include `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;`

Comment: laravel 5.4  use  _global **redirect** helper_  `$url = redirect()->intended( ... )->getTargetUrl();`

Answer (score 20):

When you are showing the form foe log in, you can grab the intended `url` from `session` if available and pass it to the view then redirect using `window.location`.

So. how to grab the `intended url` ?

```
$intended_url = Session::get('url.intended', url('/'));
Session::forget('url.intended');
```

Here, first argument is `intended url` if available in the `session` and default is set to home page using `url('/')` helper method, so the `$intended_url` will always contain a `url`, intended or defaulr. Then when you are loading the view, pass the `$intended_url` using this:

```
return View::make('login')->with('intended_url', $intended_url);
```

Then use it from the view like:

```
window.location = $intended_url;
```

Alternatively, you may setup a [View Composer](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers) so whenever the `login` view/form is displayed the `intended url` will be available in that view and you can do it using this:

```
View::composer('login', function($view){
    $intended_url = Session::get('url.intended', url('/'));
    Session::forget('url.intended');
    return $view->with('intended_url', $intended_url);
});
```

Here, `login` is the view name for login page, if this is something else in your case then change it to the appropriate name of your `login` view. You can keep this code in your `app/start` folder inside the 'global.php' file or keep it in a separate file and include this fie inside `global.php` file using this (at the end):

```
require 'view_composer.php';
```

Assumed that, file name would be `view_composer.php`, present in the `app/start` folder.

Comment: soory , i can the $intended_url in the session in no way ... no matter i've loged in or not . it's always the default value .. any idea?

Comment: According to `Sessioin::get('url.intended', url('/'))` it should return if there is any `intended url` available in the session but if not then the default `url` would be returned. After login, `intended url` is cleared from the session.

Answer (score 11):

In Laravel 5.7:

```
$url = redirect()->intended()->getTargetUrl();
```

Comment: You can pass a link to the documentation where is it?, I can't find it.

Answer (score 2):

**I am using the following approach with a custom login controller and middleware for Laravel 5.7, but I hope that works in any of laravel 5 versions**

- inside middleware

  ```
  if (Auth::check()){
      return $next($request);
  }
  else{
    return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
  }
  ```
- if you are not passing the intented url to client side use the following inside controller login method

  ```
  if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
  return redirect()->intended('/default');
  }
  ```
- If you need to pass the intented url to **client side**, you can try the following

  ```
     if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password])) {
         $intended_url= redirect()->intended('/default')->getTargetUrl();
         $response = array(
        'status' => 'success',
        'redirectUrl' => $intended_url,
        'message' => 'Login successful.you will be redirected to home..', );
        return response()->json($response);
      } else {
          $response = array(
        'status' => 'failed',
        'message' => 'username or password is incorrect', );
       return response()->json($response);
      }
  ```
- Redirect to the intented url from clientside

  ```
         success: function (data) {               
                if(data.redirectUrl){
                window.location.href = data.redirectUrl;
                }
         },
  ```