# Laravel - Redirect::intended route not working

Tags: laravel, routes

I have a laravel built blog, and to comment on a post (if you're logged out) you must login. I put a link like this:

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('login') }}">login</a> to do this.
```

This redirects to the login form, which once filled out and user is authenticated, I have this:

```
return Redirect::intended('/');
```

Which takes the user to the homepage, **not** the page they intended to be on, in this case, the page with the post that they clicked the `login` link from to be able to comment. How can I return them back to the intended url in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, `Redirect::intended('/')` works if there is a key available in the session as `url.intended` otherwise it redirects to the default `URL` which is in your case '/', so definitely you didn't put the `URL` in the session. To accomplish this, you may put the `URL` in the session using something like this:

```
Session::put('url.intended', 'url...');
```

So, probably, in the login link, you may add a query string like this:

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('login') }}?intended=1">login</a>
```

So, you can track the redirect and in that route's method (before return `View`) just put the previous `URL` in the session, using something like this:

```
if(Input::get('intended')) {
    Session::put('url.intended', URL::previous());
}
```

Then before you redirect from there, you should remove the `URL` from the session using something like this:

```
$intendedUrl = Session::get('url.intended', url('/'));
Session::forget('url.intended');
return Redirect::to($intendedUrl);
```

This should solve the issue. Also, you may check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499444/laravel-get-intended-url), could be helpful.

Comment: Hmmm.. I've been reading on this approach, but I see there are others having it too, specially issues arising with using the intended in session there seems to be issues: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5940 I would think there is a better way.

Answer (score 3):

`Redirect::intended` requires two parts to work. The first is when the user tries to access a restricted page `/orders` but they aren't logged in you redirect them to the login page via:

```
redirect()->guest('/login');
```

Then on your login post-back if authentication is successful you call:

```
redirect()->intended('/dashboard');
```