# How to check, which route is session()->get('url.intended')?

Tags: laravel

Need to write some logic based on url.intended for example if the url is route */create* show different login form and different if it's */move*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel get intended url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499444/laravel-get-intended-url)

Comment: @DilipHirapara No, let's assume we do have two routes '/send' and '/create', now I wanna check the url.intended is send or create.

Comment: Try `request()->url()` , not sure if it works

Comment: it doesn't @ChanYungKeat

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Route::current()->getName() == '/create'){
    // do something
 }
```

You can also pass it from your controller to your blade view as a parameter, not the cleanest way, but it works.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current route name and based on that do stuff;

```
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

$routeName = Route::currentRouteName();

if($routeName == 'user.create') {
    // whatever is needed.
}
```